# Android network location takes hours to update location

Tags: android, location

In my android app I use the network provider to receive location updates in a location listener and sync them to my server.  When testing, I'll take the device and drive a few hours away and com back the next day.

The problem is the listener sometimes takes a few hours to give me an updated location.  I'll leave point A and get to point B and it takes 3 hours for the device to report B as the new location.  The same happens the next day going from point B back to A.

It seems odd that it's talking so long to update the location.  The distance filter is 600m and 10 minute time interval.  Is three hours about the best I can expect from using the network provider?

On a side note, it all works perfectly using gps.

Comment: Sometimes I met the same problem too, so I am very interested in this issue. While Google Map could see location change, my app can't do it. And I must wait enough long time, sometimes more than half an hour, I could see the new location.

Comment: When you take the device to the new location, does it have Internet access? You need Internet access (either connection to Wifi or mobile data connection) to get a location using NetworkProvider.

Comment: Are there any progresses for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your code is doing (it would be helpful to see your code) but try this to get a quick location update when you first start your location updates:

```
Location networkLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
```

The distance filter and the time interval settings are suggestions, not instructions, so it's possible that it's ignoring these suggestions.

Comment: I'm actually using a listener and pass in the network provider like that.
`_locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, updateTime, updateDistance, this );`

Comment: That's fine, but the code snipped above is for a one-off location update that you can use before your other listeners get results. It generally has a resonable approximation of your location.

Comment: Tried getLastKnownLocation() but it always returns the same location the listener has.