# Android network location (time to get update)

Tags: android, networking, location

When I track user location on Android using network provider, I'm getting very long times against updates when the cell is in sleep (suspend) mode. The same issue from this post:
[Android network location takes hours to update location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299183/android-network-location-takes-hours-to-update-location).

I'm using AlarmManager to fire an intent that starts a service with a PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, wait until receive the location update from a listener and stop itself (releasing the wakelock).

**All works perfectly using the GPS provider.** All permissions are OK (fine/coarse location, wakelock).

Any idea? Thank you!

***EDIT***
Problem caused by this issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10931

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Network provider is highly inaccurate. (Roughly in the range of 3km) Hence the slow location updates, you have to move from one cell-site to another.

edit: It turns out, this is [a known issue](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10931)

Comment: Moving 20km away of my home (passing throught various different cells) I don't get any update.

Comment: hmm, that is weird, the thing is that the Network providers code is not open sourced, so I don't know how it really works.

Comment: Problem caused by this issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=10931