# When does the network provider update the location in android

Tags: android, gps, location

I use `network provider` to get location in `Android application`. Sometimes I found the location would not be changed even after I arrived at a new place. At the same time, I found the locations were changed in Google Map. So I quit and restarted my application, and the locations wasn't changed either. But after a long period, or I reboot the phone, I could see the new location.

Does any one know what's the reason ? I have used `getLastKnownLocation()` to get the latest location in my application.

**Update:**

When this problem happened, I found the cellid and LAC was changed while the location wasn't changed. So it's very strange. I think Google Map may use cellid & LAC to get the location directly, so it can get the correct location.

**More update:**

When this problem happened, I used the cellid and LAC to get the location via HTTP POST request from Google server. This location was correct.

BTW, I found my question was like this question: [Android network location takes hours to update location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6299183/android-network-location-takes-hours-to-update-location)

Comment: Google Maps is using GPS as well as NetworkProvider. When you take the device to the new location, does it have Internet access? You need Internet access (either connection to Wifi or mobile data connection) to get a location using NetworkProvider.

Comment: Yes, I have an internet access.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't trust `getLastKnownLocation()`. In my experience this isn't reliable.

You'd be better off requesting location callbacks using `LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates()`. If you only need the location once you can then unregister for the callbacks using `LocationManager.removeUpdates()` after that. If your application needs to be notified when the location changes then you can register for callbacks with a reasonable minium-time and/or minimum-distance parameter (based on whatever your application requires.

Comment: I used this method, but sometimes I still didn't get the location in time. I may wait for more than 30 minutes to get the updated results. At the same time, Google Map could work correctly.

Comment: What device are you using? What are the parameters you are passing to `requestLocationUpdates()`?

Comment: HTC G7. locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, mylistener);

Comment: @flypen why don't you reduce third parameter to 0 this will decrease the wait time

Comment: @Mohit if OP is passing 1000 as `minTime`, which is 1 second, but he sometimes has to wait 30 minutes for an update, what makes you think that reducing `minTime` from 1 second to 0 seconds will help? There is obviously some other problem here.

Comment: @DavidWasser i always pass it 0 i never checked whether is second or milliseconds sorry this is my lack